# Which is the value for a lock locked return by sp_getapplock?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have found this example to avoid run a SP if it is still running:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE some_sp AS

DECLARE @ret int,
        @lockresource sysname

SELECT @lockresource = object_name(@@procid)

BEGIN TRY
   EXEC @ret = sp_getapplock @lockresource, @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
                             @LockOwner = 'Session', @LockTimeout = 5

   IF @ret <> 0
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('Another instance of the procedure is already running, 16, 1)
      RETURN
   END

   -- Do stuff

   EXEC sp_releaseapplock @lockresource, 'Session'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTIOn
   EXEC sp_releaseapplock @lockresource, 'Session'
END CATCH
```

But I'm not sure if it is what I am looking for.

If the SP is running, what will be the value of @ret here?

```
EXEC @ret = sp_getapplock @lockresource, @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
                                 @LockOwner = 'Session', @LockTimeout = 5
```

And if it is not running, what will be its value?

I have check this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx), but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no lock is granted it'll return -1, The lock request timed out after waiting for 5 miliseconds